# Character Controller for Horizontal Shooter in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a horizontal side-scrolling shooter which I plan to release on mobile devices. How can I set up the ship so that:

- It can be moved up/down/left/right freely (with varying horizontal/vertical speeds)
- Collide and stop against obstacles (i.e. IF collision with obstacle STOP)
- Diagonal movement against horizontal plane (down + right input) should move right pressed against floor

The ship **must not** be able to pass through obstacles.

I created a custom character controller which simply adjust position based on velocity. I cannot figure out how to detect collision and avoid moving through obstacles. There must be an easier way to achieve this simple requirement.

*Note: To clarify, the camera follows the ship, it does not automatically scroll. The player can stop the ship by releasing input button.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was storing my own `velocity` vector which I was then applying using `transform.Translate`. This obviously was ignoring any collision detection and would have required a custom collision detection implementation.

Instead I found that the `Rigidbody` component contains its own `velocity` variable. That velocity value can be easily altered and the object will automatically translate and collide with obstacles. Here is an example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector2 maximumSpeed = new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f);

    void Start() {

    }

    void Update() {
        Rigidbody rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();

        velocity.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * maximumSpeed.x;
        velocity.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * maximumSpeed.y;

        rigidbody.velocity = velocity;
    }

}
```

This appears to work quite well. Comments would be appreciated :-)

Comment: The other solution that is perhaps more suitable for a player-controlled entity is to use the `CharacterController` component, which provides similar function but with some "loosened" logic to allow for the fact that the entity is player-controlled (as opposed to being a pure physics entity).  With your velocity/inertia though, it may be that you're best with the solution you have.

Comment: @Dan Cheers I will experiment with that. Is it likely that `CharacterController` would perform better?

Answer (score 1):

To start with, try making sure you've added a [collider](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.html) component to your obstacles and to your character controller.  That should be enough to stop your ship passing through the obstacles.

Comment: The ship object has a spherical collider. I am unsure as to how to make that collider work. My custom controller script simply uses velocity to translate the object. I do not know how to detect collision and cancel movement.

Comment: Take care to not enable Collider's IsTrigger checkbox.

Comment: @Kay The `IsTrigger` checkbox is not ticked. My main problem (I think) is that I have no collision detection logic in my character controller. I am not sure how this would be implemented.

Comment: @Kay I have added "Ridged Body" and now it appears to be colliding. But upon hitting ground the ship begins to rise upwards and it doesn't stop. I have Mass:1,Drag:0,Angular Drag:0.2,Gravity:No,Kinematic:No,Interpolate:None,Collision Detection: Discrete, Lock X/Z Rotation

Comment: I've found the solution now, see below. Thanks for your help, you have helped me to improve my understanding of how this works.